# how to easily group values to improve heatmap visualization

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

I am making a heatmap. I was given a dataframe, and am now comparing the values "Age" and "purch_bike" (which is a "yes" or "no" variable). I want to clean this visual up since there are so many values currently displayed on the heatmap. So I think I would like to create larger ranges for the ages, by grouping them into bins/intervals of 11. How can I do this?

Dataset: http://www.ishelp.info/data/bikebuyers_original.csv

**Current Code & Output (via Google Colab):**

```
sns.heatmap(pd.crosstab(df.Age, df.purch_bike), annot=True, fmt='d');
chi1, p_value1, dof1, expected1 = chi2_contingency(pd.crosstab(df['Age'], df['purch_bike']))
print(f'X square:\t\t{round(chi1, 4)}') # this code simply displays the Chi-square stat and p-value
print(f'p-value:\t\t{round(p_value1, 6)}')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pd.cut` from pandas groups together per range. It can be used to create a new column 'AgeGroup' to be used as input for `pd.crosstab`. The `labels` parameter of `pd.cut` can set appropriate text to be used as y-ticks. `right=False` takes care of the ages equal to a bin border, putting them in the higher bin.
Some example code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_csv('http://www.ishelp.info/data/bikebuyers_original.csv')
df.rename(columns={"Purchased Bike": "purch_bike"}, inplace=True)

# bins = list(range(0, 80, 10)) + [120]
bins = [20, 28, 35, 42, 49, 56, 63, 70, 77, 84, 91, 120]
labels = [f'{a0}-{a1 - 1}' for a0, a1 in zip(bins[:-2], bins[1:-1])] + [f'≥{bins[-2]}']
df['AgeGroup'] = pd.cut(df.Age, bins=bins, labels=labels, right=False)

sns.heatmap(pd.crosstab(df.AgeGroup, df.purch_bike), annot=True, fmt='d')
plt.yticks(rotation=0)
plt.show()
```

[image: sample plot]

Comment: And how could I create exactly 10 bins? With ages separated into 20-27, 28-34, 35-41, 42-48, 49-55, 56-62, 63-69, 70-76, 77-83, 84-90

Comment: `bins = [20, 28, 35, 42, 49, 56, 63, 70, 77, 84, 91, 120]`